# How to merge particles to new shape blender

Tags: particles, force-fields

I am looking to achieve an effect similar to the particles shown in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q93pE5jB1Uw

BUT

When the particles are in mid-air - whilst being affected by the force field, I want them to come back to the center to create a new shape or text field.

I do not want to simply merge one shape into the next - like in this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want the particles to go from one object, to free-floating, then back to another object?

Comment: @snipers500 - thanks for commenting :) yes, this is correct. That's what I am looking for but I could not seem to find any tutorials like that.

Comment: I think you could just key it from one particle system to another particle system which is free-floating, then back to the third particle system